# chartjs & asp.net: Cannot read property 'labels' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, chart.js

I have been through all the posts regarding this issue yet I can not fix it.

My chartjs line chart gets created fine.  I am trying to test updating it (adding data) but i'm stuck on the chart.data.labels.push(labels) as it states the object is undefined in the console.  Yet on the console, the line before, I write the id of the object and it is correct so it has the ref.

Any thoughts?

**Chart is created fine**

```
$(function () {
    LoadChart();
});

function LoadChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['9:30', '9:31', '9:32', '9:33', '9:34', '9:35'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'RSI',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
           title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Custom Chart Title'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Error When trying to update the chart**

```
$.connection.redisHub.client.addData = function (chartID, labels, data) {
    var chart = document.getElementById(chartID);
    console.log("chart: " + chart.id);
    chart.data.labels.push(labels);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

**Console Output**
You can see it correctly writes 'chart: myChart' to the console showing we have the object ref. correct.
[image]

**asp code calling the js function (all works well here)**

```
string[] labels = { "9:36", "9:37" };
int[] data = { 9, 10 };
Clients.All.addData("myChart", labels, data);
```

**html : all is well here**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706577/cannot-read-property-labels-of-undefined

Comment: yes i was through that post, his error was regarding the order in which he creates his initial chart.  This is different as I already have my initial chart created correctly, and am now trying to 'add' data to it, and i have the object ref on the line before.  I did my diligence in searching prior posts, thanks though

Comment: ok, can you add a console.log(labels) in var chart = document.getElementById(chartID);
    console.log("chart: " + chart.id);
    chart.data.labels.push(labels);

Comment: yes will try that and report thank u... labels is my v of data passed, do you mean chart.data.labels

Comment: console.log(labels) outputs my data passed correctly:  Array(2)
0: "9:36"
1: "9:37"
length: 2 & same error for console.log(chart.data.labels);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var chart = document.getElementById(chartID);` will return the `canvas` element, which is not an instance of Chart.js, so all of the subsequent code is invalid.

You need to use `myChart` from the `LoadChart()` function as this is a Chart.js instance (returned at instantiation). The simplest way to do this is to move the variable definition to a higher scope so that it is available to your update function.

Without knowing how your code is structured it's difficult to give a working example, but here's a simplistic example of what I mean:

```
var myChart;

$(function () {
    LoadChart();
});

function LoadChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
    ...
}

$.connection.redisHub.client.addData = function (chartID, labels, data) {
    myChart.data.labels.push(labels);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This did it!  However if I have multiple charts, say myChart1, myChart2... how can I pass the chartID to select the chart I want in addData function?  Thank you!

Comment: @MX313 Assuming that `chartID` is already being passed as the `id` attribute of the `canvas` element (based on your code) then you could perhaps store the chart references in an array, e.g. `var charts = [];` and then `charts["myChart"] = new Chart...`. Then access the correct chart via `charts[chartID].data...`.